# Java File I/O validate file contents then use those contents to create sales report

Tags: java, file-io

I'm in a **beginner** Java course...and my latest assignment seems super difficult for some reason.  The assignment is focused around File I/O.  It involves many parts, but this part is what is really confusing me. It involves:

1. Reading a Sales file where each line is supposed to have first the
   Division (N, S, E or W), then the Quarter (1-4) on the next line,
   then the Sales Amount on the third line and then repeats. **(can do
   this ok)**
2. We have to validate that each line has one of the allowable
   options/file types **(can do this ok)**
3. Then dump any errors to an error file and ask the user to supply
   another file & repeat until the input file is in the right format.
   **(have this working)**
4. Once it is in the right format, we have to be able to generate a
   sales report in the below format **(can't figure out how I am
   supposed to be able to get this collected...)**

> Sales Report
>
> Total Sales by division:
>   North $total
>   South $total
>   East $total
>   West $total
>
> Total Sales by quarter:
>   Jan-Mar $total
>   Apr-Jun $total
>   Jul-Sep $total
>   Oct-Dec $total
>
> Year End Total: $total

One menu option has to be to Validate the file is in the correct format, and then another menu option appears to generate the Sales Report.

**Note: We aren't expected to use arrays yet (that's the next assignment).**

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SalesReporting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inputData;
    String divisionRead;
    int qtrRead;
    double salesRead;
    String filePath;
    String menuChoice;
    File fileName;
    PrintWriter outputErrorLog;
    PrintWriter outputSalesReport;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputFile;
    String overwriteFile;
    Boolean isDataFileError;
    Boolean isValidSalesFile = false;
    Boolean isValidMenuChoice;
    Boolean isToOverwrite = false;

    System.out.println("\tHarmway Corporation" +
            "\nQuarterly Sales Report Generator");

    do { 
        do {
            isValidMenuChoice = true;

            // display main menu options to user & prompt for choice
            System.out.print("\n\tMain Menu" +
                "\n" +
                "\n[V]alidate Sales Data");
            // only display generate sales report option if a sales report has been validated
            if (isValidSalesFile) {
                System.out.print("\n[G]enerate Sales Report");
            }
            System.out.print("\nE[x]it program" +
                "\n");

            System.out.print("\nEnter choice: ");

            menuChoice = keyboard.next();

            if (!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("v") &&
                !menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("g") &&
                !menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
                isValidMenuChoice = false;
                System.out.print("\n\t**Error** - Invalid menu item");
            }
        } while (isValidMenuChoice == false);

        if (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
            do {
                // prompt user for the sales data file path
                System.out.print("\nSales data file path: ");
                filePath = keyboard.next();

                fileName = new File(filePath);

                // if the file path doesn't exist, error displayed
                if (!fileName.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("\n" + fileName + " not found");
                }
            } while (!fileName.exists());

            // create a scanner for the input file
            inputFile = new Scanner(fileName);

            // create an error log to dump invalid sales data errors to
            fileName = new File("errorlog.txt");
            outputErrorLog = new PrintWriter(fileName);

            // resets boolean to allow for error free data file check
            isDataFileError = false;

            // validate and store the sales data
            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {
                // first line must be division N, S, E or W to be valid
                inputData = inputFile.next();
                try 
                {
                    divisionRead = inputData;

                    if (isValidDivision(divisionRead)) {
                        System.out.println("ok division");
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        isDataFileError = true;
                        outputErrorLog.println(divisionRead + ",Invalid division value");
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    isDataFileError = true;
                    outputErrorLog.println(inputData + ",Invalid division value");
                }

                // if second line is a valid quarter
                inputData = inputFile.next();
                try 
                {
                    qtrRead = Integer.parseInt(inputData);

                    if (isValidQuarter(qtrRead)) {
                        System.out.println("ok quarter");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        isDataFileError = true;
                        outputErrorLog.println(qtrRead + ",Invalid quarter value");
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    isDataFileError = true;
                    outputErrorLog.println(inputData + ",Invalid quarter value");
                }

                inputData = inputFile.next();
                try 
                {
                    salesRead = Double.parseDouble(inputData);  

                    if (isValidSales(salesRead)) {
                        System.out.println("ok sales");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        isDataFileError = true;
                        outputErrorLog.println(salesRead + ",Invalid sales amount value");
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    isDataFileError = true;
                    outputErrorLog.println(inputData + ",Invalid sales amount value");
                }


            }


            // close the input sales data file
            inputFile.close();

            // close the error log file to write
            outputErrorLog.close();

            if (isDataFileError)
            {
                // there was an error in the sales file; not a valid sales data file
                isValidSalesFile = false;
                System.out.print("\nThe data file contains data errors"
                    + " (See error log for details)");
            }
            else
            {
                // there were no errors; valid sales data file
                isValidSalesFile = true;
                System.out.print("\nThe data file is validated");
            }
        }

        if (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("g")) {
            System.out.println("\ntemp g");

            do {
                // prompt user for file path to save sales report
                System.out.print("\nSave report as: ");
                filePath = keyboard.next();

                // identify file to be used
                fileName = new File(filePath);


                // file already exists; ask whether to overwrite file or not
                if (fileName.exists())
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nOverwrite (y/n): ");
                        overwriteFile = keyboard.next();

                        if (overwriteFile.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                        {
                            isToOverwrite = true;

                            // create printwriter for the sales data file
                            outputSalesReport = new PrintWriter(filePath);

                            System.out.println("\nGenerating sales report...");



                            // add code to write to the results to the file





                            // close sales report
                            outputSalesReport.close();

                            System.out.println("\nReport generated successfully!"); 
                        }

                    } while (!overwriteFile.equalsIgnoreCase("n") &&
                            !overwriteFile.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
                }
                // file doesn't already exist; save the file
                else if (!fileName.exists())
                {
                    // create printwriter for the sales data file
                    outputSalesReport = new PrintWriter(filePath);

                    System.out.println("\nGenerating sales report...");



                    // add code to write to the results to the file





                    // close sales report
                    outputSalesReport.close();

                    System.out.println("\nReport generated successfully!");
                }   
            } while (!isToOverwrite);


        }

        if (menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            System.out.println("\nProgram has been terminated.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    } while (!menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("x"));

}



public static boolean isValidDivision(String divisionRead) {
    if (divisionRead.equalsIgnoreCase("N") ||
            divisionRead.equalsIgnoreCase("S") ||
            divisionRead.equalsIgnoreCase("E") ||
            divisionRead.equalsIgnoreCase("W")) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isValidQuarter(int qtrRead) {
    if (qtrRead >= 1 && qtrRead <= 4) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isValidSales(double salesRead) {
    if (salesRead >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I'm not asking for specific code, but just some guidance on how I should best proceed.  Any advice would be appreciated.  I've been stuck on this assignment for over a month!

Example of what the Sales Data file would look like if in a valid format (each would be on its own line...the forum is ignoring the breaks):

N
1
35.50
N
2
26.99
N
3
77.45
N
4
58.30
S
1
132.15
S
2
81.19
S
3
159.06
S
4
83.55
E
1
99.40
E
2
25.39
E
3
50.25
E
4
43.21
W
1
120.89
W
2
392.11
W
3
105.76
W
4
299.95
N
2
66.15
N
3
38.22
N
4
27.66
E
2
135.32
E
3
37.50
E
4
9.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not dealing (not want to deal ) with arrays or collections, you can consider creating varianles for North, South, East, West, year end total and the 4 quarters update the values of these variables as you iterate through the file.

Using collection this task would be a little streamlined, but would be prettymuch the same amount of work.

to generate the actual report you can use the String classes for concatenation such as

```
String.format("%s:%s",strDivision, doubleAmount);
```

which will give you the info in the desired format, this can be extended to address the rest of the report.

I dont think you need assistance in parsing the file since you say that you are able to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Create yourself a class that contains the information you need to store (`SalesData` for example), as you validate each section of the file, create a new `SalesData` object, seeding it with the values you just read.  From there you add it to a [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation, like [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

This will allow you to loop over the list once the file has been read and produce the report.

You other choice would be to maintain a running tally of each division and quarter.  This is a little simpler and less memory intensive, but less flexible should the contents of the report change.